Derive the ripple voltage in a basic Dickson charge pump
I have spent about three days trying to derive the ripple voltage of Dickson's charge pump. Many papers I’ve read simply state that the ripple voltage is given by
$$V_r = \frac{I_LT}{C_L}$$ where \$ C_L \$ and \$ I_L\$ are capacitive load and current load, respectively. I am attempting to derive this result using a differential equation, which I will provide below.
However, my final expression seems more complicated than it should be, and I haven't been able to reduce it to the form of the ripple voltage mentioned above.
Could you provide any advice on my approach?
These are two paper where I mainly got idea from.

G. Palumbo and D. Pappalardo, "Charge Pump Circuits: An Overview on Design Strategies and Topologies," in IEEE Circuits and Systems Magazine, vol. 10, no. 1, pp. 31-45, First Quarter 2010, doi: 10.1109/MCAS.2009.935695.
B. -Y. Jaw and H. Lin, "An analysis of output ripples for PMOS charge pumps and design methodology," 2012 IEEE Asia Pacific Conference on Circuits and Systems, Kaohsiung, Taiwan, 2012, pp. 424-427, doi: 10.1109/APCCAS.2012.6419062.




Your approach includes R, the first one you present does not. Perhaps a good first step would be to check the different assumptions the two approaches make. Obviously, different assumptions will give different expressions. Sometimes, we can make radical simplifying assumptions which, although not accurate, can make a useful approximate model.

The formula you are trying to derive is the basic capacitance formula that relates capacitor current to rate of change of voltage: -
$$i=C\dfrac{dv}{dt}$$
So, the ripple voltage (\$V_{\tau}\$) is \$dv\$ and, \$dt\$ is just the relevant time period for the switching action. And, \$i\$ is the load current.
No need to go through all the stuff you have done to get this result; with perfect transfer switches and ideal capacitors, you just analyse the final stage capacitor and use the formula above to relate load current to ripple voltage.
